# HTC EVO TWRP No Kernal Installed TWRP

Tags: rooting, twrp, htc-evo

I have a freedom pop HTC EVO LTE (Jewel), and I have erased the image and no OS is installed.  I have TWRP installed and I can boot to recovery, but I am unable to flash any ROMS.  I have tried MeanBean, but the kernel install is not working and errors out.  How can I get the Kernel and or a new ROM installed so the phone will boot?

TAMPERED
UNLOCKED
S-ON
HBOOT-2.1.0000

[image: Phone Info]
[image: TWRP Info]
[image: TWRP Error]
[image: SU Error]
[image: SU Fix]

Comment: "*but I am unable to flash any ROMS*" -- can you elaborate on this part? Which TWRP version are you using? Is it official or unofficial? What ROMs have you attempted to flash so far?

Comment: I have tried cyanogenmod, and meanbean.  Cyanogenmod fails with error: can't extract binary.  Mean bean fails with error above (can't install kernal).  I am unsure what official vs unofficial twrp is.  The phone came with it on it from freedom pop.

Comment: It appears that for Meanbean ROM, data and system flashed successfully and some problem occurred when flashing kernel. Do this: in your PC, extract `boot.img` from Meanbean ROMs zip and copy it to `/sdcard` of device. Then in TWRP, go to Install, select IMG instead of ZIP option at the bottom, find and select `boot.img` under /sdcard/, and when asked for, choose boot partition. Report us the results.

Comment: Do I flash meanbean rom via zip after the boot.img?

Comment: This time: wipe System, data and all caches. Then flash Meanbean ROM. It would flash data and system fine (if I trust the screenshot) but fail at boot. For boot, follow my earlier comment.

Comment: I do not have the option to flash .img from twrp. looks like that is not available until 2.8.4.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32746/discussion-between-firelord-and-ryan-e).